# Java JNA with Pascal Performance

Tags: java, performance, pascal, jna

I have an algorithm for a timetable optmization problem written in Pascal which takes 1 to 2 hours to complete.

I want to make a graphical interface in Java for this algorithm.

I research about the Java Native Access (JNA), making a dll for the Pascal algorithm and using it in Java.

My problem is with the performance issue with this method, so I want to ask if the performance using jna+pascal will be much slower than if I used only Pascal and why.

Comment: Which Pascal exactly? If FreePascal or Delphi, I would use the LCL (Lazarus) or FMX (FireMonkey) respectively. I see no good reason to use Java for this.

Comment: But this is asking for an opinon, which is not really a good question for this community, IMO.

Comment: The version used is the FreePascal, but it was not made by me. I need to use Java especially because of a Google Maps component.

Comment: The overhead is in calling the functions, If you limit the number of calls back and forth it won't be bad.

Comment: @JoãoB: AFAIK, there are Google Maps components for FreePascal as well.